# Highchart width changes between draws

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, width, draw

I'm seeing something strange with highchart. 
I hope someone else got a fix for it.

When i first draw my chart it doesn't fill the entire parent container. (space between the chart and the next container):

[image: 1. draw]

If I let it draw again it looks as it should. (space between the chart and the next container):

[image: 2. draw]

I think the problem is the way it calculates the width.
The width isn't defined by me but by the container.
Container width is set to a 100%.

So maybe the problem is the timing of the width calculation?

I Really hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you share a code snipped or fiddle?

Comment: I will try to see if I can crate a fiddle og snip. 

The problem is hard to replicate but i will do my best. :)